# How to update a bootstrap table element in node web app when new entry is added to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bootstrap-4, node-postgres

I built a web app using node, express, and node-pg to interface with a postgres database. The web app displays values from the database in a table using the bootstrap table element.

The web app is always running displaying the table, and values are constantly being added to the database. Is there a way to update the values in the table automatically so it is always showing the most up to date information?

Comment: There are two ways to achieve this as I know. You can try socket.io(pushing from server to client) to send information to connected client to get the information whenever the dependent data updated. Otherwise you can send a ajax call periodically (long polling) to get the updated data.

Comment: @AghilanB Okay I'll check out socket.io, I'm currently just refreshing the page every 5 seconds but that seems like a inefficient solution for my purpose